# setting an alarm on weekly basis

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am developing an android app, where I am setting an alarm on weekly basis. The alarm gets set accordingly and everything works fine.
When the alarm time is less than current time,the alarm was triggering immediately. So to avoid this immediate triggering I have canceled it as

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.this, TaskRecieverForAlarm.class);
 intent.putExtra("AlarmDate", alarmdate);
 intent.putExtra("key", key);
 PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmClock.this, key , intent, 0);

if(AlarmHrsInInt < currentHrs)
 {
   am.cancel(sender);
 }

am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 7*1440*60000 ,sender);
```

But if do so, The alarm is not getting set to next week.Instead of getting canceled for current time, Its getting canceled even for next week.What should I do to set the alarm properly to next week?
Please Help.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 public static final long DAY_IN_MILLISEC = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

public void initAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, ReceiverClass.class);
    i.setAction(ReceiverClass.ALARM_INVOKE_ACTION);

    // /////Alarm Time
    Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long time = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (time <= cal.getTimeInMillis())
        time = cal.getTimeInMillis() + DAY_IN_MILLISEC;// /Will set for the
                                                        // next day
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, DAY_IN_MILLISEC, pi); // MilliSec
                                                                            // *
                                                                            // Sec
                                                                            // *
                                                                            // Mnt
                                                                            // *
                                                                            // Hour
    // /***OR
    // am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time,
    // AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 1, pi);
}
```

ReceiverClass.java

```
    public class ReceiverClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ALARM_INVOKE_ACTION = "com.test.alarm";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.e("action", "Action");
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ALARM_INVOKE_ACTION)) {
            Log.e("Alarm Invoke", "YES");
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED)
                || action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)
                || action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)
                || action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)
                || action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_REBOOT)) {
            Log.e("RESET ALARM HERE.SET AGAIN", "YES");
        }

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml
add ...

```
<receiver android:name="com.hiddenbrains.ui.screens.ReceiverClass" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.test.alarm" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: I tried this code.Its working fine.But the first time, I try setting alarm time which is less than current time, its again triggering immediately. Further if I set alarm time which is less than current time.There is no alarm triggering.All the alarms are set properly to next week. How to avoid first immediate triggering?

Comment: i gve u for day repeat alarm.For week repeatweek you need to give time millisec for 7 days ... public static final long WEEK_IN_MILLISEC = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

Comment: ya I have tried as 7*1440*60000 i.e  1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 in place of DAY_IN_MILLISEC for above code.Even then its not set for next week.

Comment: you also need reset alarms on TIMEZONE_CHANGED & TIME_CHANGED ACTION ....<action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" /> ...i think for testing u r changing time from settings.so you need to set alarm again if u change time,timezone etc
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />

Answer (score 0):

Issue only setrepeating as suggested by @user1140237

Comment: dont check in hours.. i mean if condition. Convert current time to milli seconds and thn compare with alarm invoke time in milli seconds

Comment: can you guide me in converting current time to milliseconds?

Comment: check the code again, the alaram is set for next day not after 7days. try changing your dateand time by one day and test again. the code given by @user1140237 should work.